# Android TV, intercepting Dropbox SDK calls to redirect to WebView

Tags: android, android-intent, dropbox, television

I am developing an Android TV version of my app with Dropbox connectivity. Since many Android TV devices don't have browsers, I want to intercept the login intent and show the login + scope permissions grant pages in a WebView.

I modified my manifest, but the intent doesn't open my activity anyway. Any suggestions?
Here's my manifest:

```
        <activity
        android:name=".ActivityWebView">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.APP_BROWSER" />
        <data android:scheme="" android:host="www.dropbox.com"/>
        <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.dropbox.com"/>
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.dropbox.com"/>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Did you add `android:exported='true'` and `android:enabled='true'` to your activity?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've already taken a different approach to this.